# How do i access my custom gateway options through my controller?

Tags: custom-options, payment-methods, payment-gateway, system.xml

I have created a custom gateway payment.
I defined some custom options in my "system.xml" like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <sections>
    <payment>
      <groups>
        <gwpay translate="label comment" module="paygate">
          <label>GWPay</label>
          <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
          <sort_order>2</sort_order>
          <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
          <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
          <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
          <fields>
            <active translate="label">
              <label>Enabled</label>
              <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
              <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
              <sort_order>10</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
            </active>
            <title translate="label">
              <label>Title</label>
              <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
              <sort_order>20</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            </title>
            <allowspecific translate="label">
              <label>Payment Applicable From</label>
              <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
              <sort_order>61</sort_order>
              <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_payment_allspecificcountries</source_model>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
            </allowspecific>
            <specificcountry translate="label">
              <label>Countries Payment Applicable From</label>
              <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
              <sort_order>70</sort_order>
              <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
              <depends>
                <allowspecific>1</allowspecific>
              </depends>
            </specificcountry>
            <sort_order translate="label">
              <label>Sort Order</label>
              <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
          <sort_order>80</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
            </sort_order>
            <iframe translate="label">
              <label>IFRAME payment</label>
              <frontend_type>checkbox</frontend_type>
              <sort_order>82</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
            </iframe>
            <iframe_width translate="label">
              <label>IFRAME width (px/%)</label>
              <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
              <sort_order>83</sort_order>
            </iframe_width>
            <iframe_height translate="label">
              <label>IFRAME height (px/%)</label>
              <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
              <sort_order>84</sort_order>
            </iframe_height>
          </fields>
        </gwpay>
      </groups>
    </payment>
  </sections>
</config>
```

My question is, how do i access the values of these custom options in php?
Can i access them from my controller, or through the "order" object? if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you need to know active field value, Then try following way.

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/gwpay/active')
```

From any where you can get actual data inside magento.

Comment: Tip: For this specific setting it is good practice to implement it in your module helper and extend isModuleEnabled, from [Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Abstract.php).

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can get any system xml value by using below syntax 
Suppose want to  title field value

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('selctionname/GroupName/fieldName');
```

**Section name** is `payment`

```
<sections>
    <payment> <!-- this section name -->
```

**Group name is gwpay** According to

```
<groups>
        <gwpay translate="label comment" module="paygate"><!-- gwpay  is group name-->
```

**Field Name is  title** as it under the tag

```
 <fields>..
...
<title translate="label"> <!-- title is field name -->
              <label>Title</label>
```

**Now you can field value by**

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/gwpay/title')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, i would vote it up if i had enough reputation....